# Trouble handling intersection of an SKSpriteNode and any instance of an SKShapeNode

Tags: sprite-kit

i have an SKSpriteNode thats named shipNode and a subclass of SKShapeNode in which I instantiate 100 times. How do you handle the ship node touching any of the SKShapeNodes? Can I just use the intersects method?

```
if shipNode.intersects("WHAT DO I PUT HERE?")
{
```

Comment: Are you not working with physics bodies? You should just consult apple documentation when you do not know how a function works.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483140-intersects

Comment: BTW 100 SKShapeNodes is a bad idea,  as a newbie go ahead and use it to learn, but when you get serious about your code, try to switch to better alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

creating your own physics system is an involved process, and likely less performant that using the built-in Box2d for anything other than rectangles.

However, the basic syntax (for rectangles):

`if player.frame.intersects(enemy.frame) { endGame() }`

Comment: SKNode has it's own built in intersects method,  it is pretty much a forward method to frame.intersects

Comment: Please elaborate on using physics bodies

Comment: @Tim2799 what do you want to happen on collision?

Comment: I want the collision to call a method to end the game